# How do I cleanup a Thread after its run method finishes?

Tags: java, multithreading

What should be done with a Thread after its `run()` method finishes executing? Is there any cleanup needed for a Thread in Java?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unless the thread's work has used some unmanaged resources (network streams, files etc) - in which case *it* should clean up after itself - there's nothing you need to do.

Note that holding a reference to the `Thread` object representing the thread won't keep the underlying OS thread alive.

Comment: Also worth noting pointing out that a Thread object doesn't always represent a OS thread just like a File object doesn't always represent a "real" file.

Comment: The thread is dynamically creating classes and loading them .... eventually the ClassLoader would run out of memory? If yes, how do we clean up that?

Comment: @Stackee007: You'd need to create a separate ClassLoader specifically for that, and allow it (and all the classes it's created) to be garbage collected. I don't see how this is particularly relevant to the original question though.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to, thread exits , once `run` method finishes it's execution

Answer (score 8):

Generally cleaning up is done by the garbage collector. If the threads uses files/sockets you may need to close them. The best practice is to close resources in the top-level `finally` block in `Thread::run`.

Actually, you need to clean up your data, and not the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Nopes. The thread would execute and die on its own and get garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

No its not necessary. When the thread exit its run method, the thread come into exit state itself.